# Using the closedness of the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ to determine that $0_{\mathbb C} \in \sigma(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I have the operator $T \in \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C))$ defined as
$$
Tx_n = \frac {x_n} n \,.
$$
I am supposed to show that $0$ is in the spectrum of $T$, $\sigma(T)$, knowing that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$ and that $\sigma(T)$ is closed.

The spectrum of a linear bounded operator $T$ (on this particular space) was defined as
\begin{equation}\label{eq:spectrum}
\sigma(T) = \left\{ \lambda \in \mathbb C \mid (\lambda I - T)^{-1} \notin \mathcal L(\ell^2(\mathbb C)) \right\} \,. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

#### An incomplete attempt

We know that $\sigma(T)$ is closed, so it contains all of its accumulation points.
To show $0 \in \sigma(T)$, one approach might then be to show that $0$ is one of the accumulation points of $\sigma(T)$.

If this was the case, then there should be a sequence $(\sigma_n)\subset\sigma(T)$,
for which
$$
\Vert 0 - \sigma_n \Vert_2
= \Vert \sigma_n \Vert_2
= \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sigma_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} < \varepsilon,
$$
for some large enough $n$. As $\sigma_n \in \sigma(T)$ for all $n$, by \eqref{eq:spectrum} we know that the operator $\sigma_n I - T$ is not bounded nor linear.

But then what? Does $0$ not being an eigenvalue step into the equation here somehow?

Comment: As you've written your operator, your statement is not true. Do you mean $(Tx)_n=\frac{x_n}{n}$?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yup. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we easily see that if $e^n_k=\delta_{n,k}$ (the Kronecker delta), then $Te^n=\frac{1}{n} e^n$. Accordingly, $\frac{1}{n}\in \sigma(T)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\sigma(T)$ is closed, we get that $0=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\in\sigma(T)$.

Alternatively, you can simply say that $T-0\cdot I=T,$ which is injective with $(T^{-1}x)_n=n x_n$ for $x\in T(\ell^2)$. Since $\| T^{-1} e^n\|_{\ell^2}=n,$ we see, directly, that $T^{-1}$ is not bounded.

A third approach is to show that $T$ is not surjective. This also isn't too bad as, for instance, the sequence given by $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is clearly not in the image of $T$.

Comment: In the first approach, which seems like the one I was supposed to use, it seems like you took no advantage of the fact that $0$ is not an eigenvalue, but instead of the fact that $1/n$ is. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ can we conclude that $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$?

Comment: Yes. Because $T-\lambda I$ is not injective and hence, not invertible.

Comment: Agh, nevermind. Its right in the definition. For $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $T$, it has to be in $\sigma(T)$.

Comment: I have to say, even after all these weeks I'm still mixing up my norms and zeroes. That makes problems like these very difficult.

Comment: Well, I mean... for this exercise you aren't using the $\ell^2$-norm for anything in particular. The above (except for point three) is true for *any* norm on $\textrm{span}\{e^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $T$ defines a bounded operator.